# How can I bind a Canvas Object in a class on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, events, event-handling, tkinter-canvas

```py
from tkinter import *
from random import randint as rnd

class SpaceField:
    def __init__(self, window = None):
        self.window = window
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Asteriods")
        # Define canvas size and active flag
        self.wide, self.high, self.active = 700, 600, True
        self.canvas_display()
        self.asteriod_creation_seperation()
        self.spaceship_creation()
        self.spaceship_movement()
        #self.bullet_creation()

# Start Up

    def spaceship_creation(self):
        self.shipcoords = [] #Dont forget to append
        self.spaceship = self.canvas.create_polygon(340,300,360,
            300, 350,280, outline ="white")
        self.shipcoords.append(self.spaceship)

# Creation of the spaceship

    def spaceship_movement(self):
        self.spaceshipx, self.spaceshipy = 10, 10
        self.canvas.move(self.spaceship, self.spaceshipx, self.spaceshipy)

# Movement of the Spaceship

    def down(self, event):
        print(event.keysym)
        self.spacehipx = 0
        self.spaceshipy = -10

# Event that triggers movement, from the down arrow. Right now it only prints the "down" which means it is sensing I am pressing it, but other than that doesn't move the space ship. Which is what I want.

    def asteriod_creation_seperation(self):
        self.asteroids, self.speed = [], []
        size, radius = 50, 25
        for i in range(25):
            spacex = rnd(size, self.wide - size)
            spacey = rnd(size, self.high - size)
            self.asteroids.append( # Store oval item id
                self.canvas.create_oval(
                    spacex, spacey, spacex+size, spacey+size,
                    width=2, tags = "asteriod", outline = "white"))
            self.speed.append((rnd(1,4),rnd(1,4))) # Store random speed x, y

# Creation of the Asteroids

    def asteriod_update(self): # MAIN DRIVER: Work on ALL asteroids
        for i, a in enumerate(self.asteroids):
            xx, yy = self.speed[i] # get speed data
            x, y, w, h = self.canvas.coords(a)
            # check for boundary hit then change direction and speed
            if x < 0 or w > self.wide:
                xx = -xx * rnd(1, 4)
            if y < 0 or h > self.high:
                yy = -yy * rnd(1, 4)

            # Limit max and min speed then store it
            self.speed[i] = (max( -4, min( xx, 4)), max( -4, min( yy, 4 )))
            self.canvas.move(a, xx, yy) # update asteroid position

# Movement of the Asteroids

    def move_active(self):
        if self.active:
            self.asteriod_update()
            self.window.after(40, self.move_active)

# Updating the Asteroids Position

    def canvas_display(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(
            self.window, width = self.wide,
            height = self.high, background = "black")
        self.canvas.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")

# Displaying the Canvas

    def run(self): # Begin asteroids here so that mainloop is executed
        self.window.bind("<KeyPress-Down>", lambda e: SpaceF.down(e))
        self.window.after(200, self.move_active)
        self.window.mainloop()


# Binding Keys and running mainloop

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SpaceF = SpaceField()

    SpaceF.run()
```

To summarize I want to move the spaceship down using the Downward Arrow Key, but I do not know how to make it move. I think I might have to use an if statement, but any help or a video recommendation would help as well.

Comment: I edited you question to put the descriptive parts as part of code comments because it is otherwise hard to copy the code and run it since it is separated, it also makes it harder to read it, also you need to provide a [mre] and don't ask for recommendations

Comment: the issue is that you are only changing the value of attributes when you need to also move the object on canvas for example by using `self.canvas.move` (which is documented so go read the docs), also it should be written like this: `self.window.bind("<KeyPress-Down>", self.down)` instead of what you have there. And your code probably should be restructured for example the spaceship should be its own class and so should be the asteroids, also the given class could inherit from `Tk` and instance attributes should be defined in `__init__` method for clarity or sth

Comment: I think I understand, I am a not used to using classes but I will try. Also can you provide a link for the docs?

Comment: you could literally just google _tkinter canvas.move docs_ and the second result (for me) was the the docs (the method is somewhere between since all the methods are listed): https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas-methods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that demonstrates how to move your spacecraft around at different speeds.

I've given two ways of achieving it.

1. Use conditional statements
2. Use list indexing of alternatives

Also you need to make sure canvas has the focus.

```py
class SpaceField:
    def __init__(self, window = None):
        ...

        self.canvas.bind("<Down>", self.down)
        self.canvas.bind("<Up>", self.up)

    def down(self, event):
        if event.state == 262144: # Open key
            y = 1
        elif event.state == 262145: # Shift key
            y = 5
        else: # Control key
            y = 10
        self.canvas.move(self.spaceship, 0, y)

    def up(self, event):
        y = [-1, -5, -10][[262144, 262145, 262148].index(event.state)]
        self.canvas.move(self.spaceship, 0, y)

    def run(self): # Begin asteroids here so that mainloop is executed
        self.window.after(200, self.move_active)

        # make sure canvas has the focus
        self.canvas.focus_force()
        self.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Derek, how would I make the Canvas the focus? Also out of the two ways, what is the most. I don't know to say this "Best"/"Effective" @Derek

Comment: @user14232195 to focus you can use `.focus_set()` (or `.focus_force()`) and out of the two ways the faster seems to be using `if/elif` because you don't need to create a list and then also find an index and then use that index for an index for the other list (could also use dictionaries in a similar fashion: `states = {262144: -1, ...}` and so on, so it would be used as `self.canvas.move(self.spaceship, 0, states[event.state])` but also create the dictionary in the `__init__` method (as should do if using the list as such) so that it doesn't get created each time the function is called)

Comment: I supplied two methods in order to give choice @user14232195.